# Windows Forms TreeView - Bind hierarchical recursive datasource

Tags: c#, winforms, treeview, recursive-datastructures

I'm converting a WPF client in Windows Forms and I got some problems trying to replicate the TreeView control structure.

In the first project I have a custom factory that builds a structure starting from an input string that is basically a XML.
The return type is a collection.
Custom TreeNode:

```
public class TreeViewNode
{
    public TreeViewNode() { }
    public DocumentKey DocKey { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public IList<TreeViewNode> Children { get; set; }
}
```

Factory:

```
public class TreeViewFactory
{
    public IList<TreeViewNode> GetSctructure(DocumentKey docKey, string structure, bool loadAllParents)
    {
        XDocument xmlDocstructure = CommonXmlValueParser.GetXDocument(structure);

        var parentsNodes = (from item in xmlDocstructure.Descendants("structure_item")
                            where (CommonXmlValueParser.GetAttribute(item, "level") == "1")
                            select new TreeViewNode
                            {
                                Text = GetNodeText(item),
                                DocKey = new DocumentKey()
                                {
                                    Bank = docKey.Bank,
                                    Ud = int.Parse(CommonXmlValueParser.GetElement(item.Element("ud"))),
                                    Master = int.Parse(CommonXmlValueParser.GetElement(item.Element("master"))),
                                    NVig = int.Parse(CommonXmlValueParser.GetElement(item.Element("nvig"))),
                                    Subjects = docKey.Subjects
                                },
                                Children = GetChildrenNodes(item, 2, docKey.Bank)
                            }).ToList();

        return parentsNodes;
    }


    private IList<TreeViewNode> GetChildrenNodes(XElement element, int level, int dataBank)
    {
        var childrenNodes = (from item in element.Descendants("structure_item")
                             where (CommonXmlValueParser.GetAttribute(item, "level") == level.ToString())
                             select new TreeViewNode
                             {
                                 Text = GetNodeText(item),
                                 DocKey = new DocumentKey()
                                 {
                                     Bank = dataBank,
                                     Ud = int.Parse(CommonXmlValueParser.GetElement(item.Element("ud"))),
                                     Master = int.Parse(CommonXmlValueParser.GetElement(item.Element("master"))),
                                     NVig = int.Parse(CommonXmlValueParser.GetElement(item.Element("nvig"))),
                                 },
                                 Children = GetChildrenNodes(item, level + 1, dataBank)
                             }).ToList();

        return childrenNodes;
    }
}
```

Binding:

```
void CreateTree(object tree, EventArgs e)
{
    //...
    TreeViewFactory treeFactory = new TreeViewFactory();
    var documentStructure = treeFactory.Structure(document.DocumentKey, document.XmlStructure, true);
    this.tabMainControl.document.SetTreeViewStructureNodes(documentStructure);
}

public void SetTreeViewStructureNodes(IList<TreeViewNode> nodes)
{ 
    this.treeView.ItemsSource = nodes;
}
```

**Update:**

I made the TreeViewNode derive from TreeNode and changed the method SetTreeViewStructureNodes in:

```
private TreeView SetTreeViewStructureNodes(IList<TreeViewNode> nodes)
{
    TreeView treeView = new TreeView();
    treeView.Nodes.AddRange(nodes.ToArray());

    return treeView;
}
```

still that doesn't achieve my goal as it's still not rendered...

In Windows Forms as far as I know it's not possible to associate a sort of datasource that is a whatever type collection (implements IEnumerable).
Apart from using 3rd party components, how can I solve my problem. My experience on WinForms is pretty short and just when I learnt to manage much better WPF they decided to shift it :(

Appreciate all your help, regards.

**Update2**:
Piece of WinForms User Control where treeView is filled:

```
TreeView treeView = (TreeView)documentViewControl.Controls["treeViewStructure"];


TreeViewFactory treeFactory = new TreeViewFactory();
var documentStructure = treeFactory.GetStructure(document.DocumentKey, document.XmlStructure, true);
treeView = this.SetTreeViewStructureNodes(documentStructure);
```

Basically I'm moving from an UC to another. Both of them are part of 2 Tabs, children of a TabControl.

Comment: What about all the comments? O_o''

Comment: 4 days have passed and no one is able to answer this? I wonder where all the winforms gurus are hiding... I have just opened a bounty on this. So as to make you realize all the possible answers to this require a horrible amount of unneeded code behind, and that you should really not switch from 21th century WPF back to the horrible archaic stone age of winforms.

Comment: I've done it myself but appreciate how much you care.
By the way, it didn't require so much code, that was more a design problem.
Thx for the 50+ :)

Comment: ok, if you already solved this, either delete the question or post an answer.  I'm still trying to understand why would anyone go back from WPF to winforms...

Comment: private TreeNode[] GetTreeViewNodes(IList<TreeViewNode> nodes)
    {
        IList<TreeNode> returnedNodes = new List<TreeNode>();
        foreach (var item in nodes)
        {
            TreeNode node = new TreeNode(item.Text,this.GetTreeViewNodes(item.Children));
            node.Tag = item.DocKey;
            returnedNodes.Add(node);  
        }

        return returnedNodes.ToArray();
    }

@Highcore You're not supposed to understand or answer "use WPF instead". The request was clear and it's an explicit one coming from the customer and PMO...so I could not help it. Simple and clear.

Comment: post it as an answer and mark it as answered so I can close the bounty too.

Answer (score 1):

(Answered by the OP as a question edit. Converted to a community wiki answer. See [Question with no answers, but issue solved in the comments (or extended in chat)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251597/question-with-no-answers-but-issue-solved-in-the-comments) )

The OP wrote:

> Actually I got that on my own. The idea is to mutuate the ricursive idea, creating one TreeNode from the collection (IList) of TreeViewNodes. Problem 1: recursion Problem 2: how to mantain the DocKey custom property

```
private TreeNode[] GetTreeViewNodes(IList<TreeViewNode> nodes)
{
    IList<TreeNode> returnedNodes = new List<TreeNode>();
    foreach (var item in nodes)
    {
        TreeNode node = new TreeNode(item.Text, this.GetTreeViewNodes(item.Children));
        node.Tag = item.DocKey;
        returnedNodes.Add(node);
    }

    return returnedNodes.ToArray();
}
```

> And the code required for the treeview becomes this one:

```
this.treeView.Nodes.Clear();
this.treeView.Nodes.AddRange(this.GetTreeViewNodes(documentStructure));
```